# c# = add script tag to all of my html images simultaneously

Tags: c#, html

I have about a thousand images on my site, and I need to add a script tag `<%=Settings.MyDomain%>` to all of them. It will be a very long process unless I could find some way to add the tag to all of the images that need it. Any ideas?

Comment: Visual Studio Find+Replace. CTRL+F > Click Arrow on top left > Change Bottom dropdown to "Current Project" > Replace All

Comment: *please excuse my lack of proper etiquette* Even first time posters can take the time to read [ask] on the [help] *before* asking.

Comment: Even with Find and Replace, it's a manual process. If it helps, consider using Regex in Search options. It may help you narrow your replace cases. I hope you are using source control so you can roll back your changes if you screw up the Replace operation... :-)

Answer (score 1):

in visual studio, Ctrl + F, and use find and replace

Answer (score 0):

You can use search and replace, but you probably won't get very far, since the image tags are not all the same. In this case you can use the Visual Studio option of Regex replace. There you can use regular expressions to replace your text, which allows you to not look for exact matches, for matches to a pattern.

How the Regex will look of course depends on how your search/replace texts look, but for general information you can check [the respective MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx).